# scikit-learn: Custom feature selection within each CV fold

Tags: python, scikit-learn, feature-selection

I would like to do a random search over a large hyperparameter grid. One of the hyperparameters I’d like to optimize is feature selection. scikit-learn provides some very useful functionality for this, like the `RFECV` class, but this is not compatible with all models, since some don’t expose `coef_` or `feature_importances_` attributes. So I would like to compare RFECV with univariate feature selection. In particular, I would like to keep all features with associations to my dependent variable that are statistically significant at uncorrected p < 0.05 in univariate analyses. However, my modelling strategy for the data is fairly complex, such that it’s not an option to use one of the existing scikit-learn classes like `SelectKBest` or `SelectFdr` to apply a simple univariate statistical test. At the same time, I am wary of simply pre-calculating the significant univariate associations on the entire dataset because this seems to mix training and test data.

The easiest way to address this that I can see is to pre-calculate the significant univariate associations *for the subset of the data in each cross-validation split*, and then implement a custom feature selection function that reads these from a text file. I understand from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25250654/how-can-i-use-a-custom-feature-selection-function-in-scikit-learns-pipeline) that I can create a custom feature selection object that takes the cross-validation object in its constructor:

```py
class ExternalSelector():
    """
    Univariate feature selection by reading pre-calculated results
    for each CV split. 
    """

    def __init__(self, cv):
        self.cv = cv
        self.feature_subset = None

    def transform(self, X, y=None, **kwargs):
        split_idx = 0
        for train_idxs, test_idxs in cv:
            # read the file

            # subset X

            split_idx = split_idx + 1

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def get_params(self):
```

... but reviewing sklearn's [univariate feature selection source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/1495f6924/sklearn/feature_selection/univariate_selection.py), I can’t figure out how or even whether it’s possible to return a list of `X`s for each split.

How can I implement a custom feature selection function that reads a different list of features for each cross-validation split?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did ultimately figure out a solution that won't win any style points but does work for my application. I held the splits constant and pre-calculated the significant univariate results in a different language (R). I then wrote a custom feature selection function that infers the index of the current splits based on the indices of the observations (rows) in the current training split (`X`), given the entire dataset (`Xall`). The index of the current split is then used to read the precalculated features for that particular split in from a file.

```
class PrecalculatedSelector():
    """
    Univariate feature selection by reading pre-calculated results
    for each split. 
    """

    def __init__(self, cv, Xall, yall):
        self.cv = cv
        self.Xall = Xall
        self.yall = yall
        self.features = None

    def transform(self, X, y=None, **kwargs):
        return X[self.features]

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        # infer split index from sample indices
        samples = list(X.index)
        sample_idxs = [idx for idx, item in enumerate(self.Xall.index) if \
                       item in samples]
        counter = 0
        split_idx = -1
        for train_idxs, test_idxs in self.cv.split(self.Xall, self.yall):
            counter += 1
            if list(train_idxs) == sample_idxs:
                split_idx = counter
                break

        # read univariate results from file
        feature_dir = ...
        feature_file = feature_dir + "/split-{}.csv".\
            format(split_idx)
        with open(feature_file, 'r') as f:
            self.features = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]

        return self
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out [`GenericUnivariateSelect`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.GenericUnivariateSelect.html#sklearn.feature_selection.GenericUnivariateSelect), it seems ideal for your case.

Here is an example of how you can use it in CV:

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import GenericUnivariateSelect, f_classif
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline


X = np.array([[1, 1, 0],
             [1, 0, 0],
             [0, 1, 1],
             [0, 0, 1],
             [0, 0, 0]])

Y = np.array([1, 1, 0, 0, 1])

cv = KFold(5, random_state=1).split(X)
feature_selector = GenericUnivariateSelect(f_classif, 'fwe', 0.05) # select p-value threshold of 0.05
model = LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs')

pipe = Pipeline([
    ('feature', feature_selector),
    ('logreg', model)
])

for i, (train_idx, test_idx) in enumerate(cv):
  pipe.fit(X[train_idx], Y[train_idx])
  score = pipe.score(X[test_idx], Y[test_idx])
  print("Feature selected for fold {} is {}".format(i, pipe.named_steps['feature']._get_support_mask()))
```

Output:

```
# Feature selected for fold 0 is [False False  True]
# Feature selected for fold 1 is [False False  True]
# Feature selected for fold 2 is [False False  True]
# Feature selected for fold 3 is [False False  True]
# Feature selected for fold 4 is [ True False  True]
```

You can replace `f_classif` with your own function such that it returns **scores and pvalues** for all features

Comment: Thanks but this doesn’t really answer my question for a couple reasons. First, GenericUnivariateSelect seems to have options for percentile, k-best, FDR, FPR, and FWER but not an arbitrary uncorrected p-value. Second - and this is my fault - I neglected to mention that my modeling strategy basically cannot be run in python and so implementing my own f_classif function isn’t really feasible.