# How to manually select features for Scikit-Learn model regression?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, feature-selection

There are various methods for doing [automated feature selection](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.feature_selection) in Scikit-learn.

E.g.

```
my_feature_selector = SelectKBest(score_func=f_regression, k=3)
my_feature_selector.fit_transform(X, y)
```

The selected features are then retrievable using

```
feature_idx = my_feature_selector.get_support(indices=True)
feature_names = X.columns[feature_idx]
```

(Note, in my case `X` and `y` are Pandas dataframes with named columns).

They are also saved as an attribute of a fitted model:

```
feature_names = my_model.feature_names_in_
```

However, I want to build a pipeline with a manual (i.e. pre-specified) set of features.

Obviously, I could manually select the features from the full data-set every time I do training or prediction:

```
model1_feature_names = ['MedInc', 'AveRooms', 'Latitude']
model1.fit(X[model1_feature_names], y)
y_pred1 = model1.predict(X[model1.feature_names_in_])
```

But I want a more convenient way to construct different models (or pipelines) each of which uses a potentially different set of (manually specified) features.  Ideally, I would specify the `feature_names_in_` as an initialization parameter so that later I don't have to worry about transforming the data and can run my model (or pipeline) on the full data set as follows:

```
model1.fit(X, y)  # uses a pre-defined sub-set of features in X
model2.fit(X, y)  # uses a different sub-set of features
y_pred1 = model1.predict(X)
y_pred2 = model2.predict(X)
```

Do I need to build a [custom feature selector](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65178066/1609514) to do this?  Surely there's an easier way.

I guess I was expecting to find something like a built-in `FeatureSelector` class that I could use in a pipeline as follows:

```
my_feature_selector1 = FeatureSelector(feature_names=['MedInc', 'AveRooms', 'Latitude'])
my_feature_selector1.fit_transform(X, y)  # This would do nothing

pipe1 = Pipeline([('feature_selector', my_feature_selector1), ('model', LinearRegression())])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`ColumnTransformer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html) for column selection. In the current case, you want to ***passthrough*** important columns and ***drop*** the un-important ones:

```py
my_feature_selector1 = ColumnTransformer([
  ("selector", "passthrough", ['MedInc', 'AveRooms', 'Latitude'])
], remainder = "drop")
```

It is worth pointing out that `ColumnTransformer` supports both name-based and index-based column selection lists.

Comment: Thanks.  I saw that but didn't realize it could be used in this simple way.